# <a> Tag in HTML with a height of 40px has the text floating in the top, not in the center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a navigation bar to work. I have `<a>` tags in `<p>` tags, I want the `<a>` tags to be taking up the entire width of the navigation bar, in a way that it is clickable in all the vertical space of that specific element.

My Code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.flexmaker {
    display: flex;
}

.navlink {
    margin: auto 10px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="./stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Test Website v9</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <p class="flexmaker"><a class="navlink"href="./formpage.html">Form Page</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But my problem is that the text inside the `a` tag isn't vertically centered. I can't put it down with 
`transform: translateY()`, as that would offset the link way too low.

I am really new to both CSS and HTML, so don't judge me if I don't have the most efficient code, or not the best way of doing something.

How do I get this to center align vertically? And if my code is bad, I would appreciate it if any improvements could be suggested.

Comment: Use padding instead of implicitly setting the height

Comment: It will be, see my answer below

Comment: Woah, your solution makes it possible to omit the <p> tags entirely. That wouldn't have come to my mind even if I worked on this a whole day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implicitly defining the height of the links, use padding to get the desired height:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    position: relative;
}

.flexmaker {
    display: flex;
}

.navlink {
    padding:16px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="./stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Test Website v9</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <p class="flexmaker"><a class="navlink"href="./formpage.html">Form Page</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your css code to this for center align vertical.

```
  * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #navbar {
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        height: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .navlink {
        margin: auto 10px;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0%;
        transform: translate(0%,-50%);
    }
```

for both horizontal and vertical center change left to 50%  and translate(-50%, -50%).

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.flexmaker {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navlink {
    margin: auto 10px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="./stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Test Website v9</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <p class="flexmaker"><a class="navlink"href="./formpage.html">Form Page</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add 'align-items: center;' to '.flexmaker'

And navlink stay clear.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.flexmaker {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navlink {
    margin: auto 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="./stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Test Website v9</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            <p class="flexmaker"><a class="navlink"href="./formpage.html">Form Page</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this solution will vertically center the links as the OP wants, it will not make the space above and below the link, within the navbar, clickable, which is also desired.